# Why is ExitProcess necessary under Win32 when you can use a RET?

Tags: winapi, assembly

I've noticed that many assembly language examples built using straight Win32 calls (no C Runtime dependency) illustrate the use of an explicit call to ExitProcess() to end the program at the end of the entry-point code.  I'm not talking about using ExitProcess() to exit at some nested location within the program. There are surprisingly fewer examples where the entry-point code simply exits with a RET instruction. One example that comes to mind is the famous [TinyPE](http://www.phreedom.org/research/tinype/), where the program variations exit with a RET instruction, because a RET instruction is a single byte.  Using either ExitProcess() or a RET both seem to do the job.

A RET from an executable's entry-point returns the value of EAX back to the Windows loader in KERNEL32, which ultimately propagates the exit code back to NtTerminateProcess(), at least on Windows 7.  On Windows XP, I think I remember seeing that ExitProcess() was even called directly at the end of the thread-cleanup chain.

Since there are many respected optimizations in assembly language that are chosen purely on generating smaller code, I wonder why more code floating around prefers the explicit call to ExitProcess() rather than RET.  Is this habit or is there another reason?

In its purest sense, wouldn't a RET instruction be preferable to a direct call to ExitProcess()?  A direct call to ExitProcess() seems akin to exiting your program by killing it from the task manager as this short-circuits the normal flow of returning back to where the Windows loader called your entry-point and thus skipping various thread cleanup operations?

I can't seem to locate any information specific to this issue, so I was hoping someone could shed some light on the topic.

Comment: Are you sure these programs have their code as the PE entry point, and not the C runtime? Even so, IIRC there's always an ExitProcess waiting on the stack above the executable's entry point (judging from what I've seen from Windows stack traces; I'm not sure if this is fully correct).

Comment: It is a unixism, crept into Windows most of all due to the C language.  A counter-example is .NET, the process keeps running as long as it has any non-background threads.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about a pure assembly language program without the CRT dependency.  In the case of using the C Runtime Library, I'd imagine you'd always want to return from main or WinMain with a RET to allow _mainCRTStartup/_WinMainCRTStartup to regain control so proper cleanup can be done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your main function is being called from the C runtime library, then exiting will result in a call to ExitProcess() and the process will exit.

If your main function is being called directly by Windows, as may well be the case with assembly code, then exiting will only cause the *thread* to exit.  The process will exit *if and only if* there are no other threads.  That's a problem nowadays, because even if *you* didn't create any threads, Windows may have created one or more on your behalf.

As far as I know this behaviour is not properly documented, but is described in Raymond Chen's blog post, ["If you return from the main thread, does the process exit?"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100827-00/?p=13023).

(I have also tested this myself on both Windows 7 and Windows 10 and confirmed that they behaved as Raymond describes.)

*Addendum:* in recent versions of Windows 10, the process loader is itself multi-threaded, so there will *always* be additional threads present when the process first starts.

Comment: Your summary along with the link answered the question perfectly - I appreciate it!

Comment: I *think* Windows (the kernel) places the address of ExitProcess on the stack before jumping to the entry point of a PE executable, like @andlabs commented.  Since statically linked Windows executables aren't possible (AFAIK), the appropriate DLL will always be mapped into your process's address space, so the kernel can always do this.  i.e. RET takes you to ExitProcess even if didn't link with the CRT startup code and defined `_start` yourself.  In your testing, did you call `ExitThread` yourself, or did you look at what function RET from the entry point took you into?

Comment: @PeterCordes: my test program returned from the main function.  This did not cause the process to exit.

Comment: Using Win7 64-bit and a 32-bit pure asm program, after the entry-point RET, I returned to an unnamed point in KERNEL32 nested from  ntdll.___RtlUserThreadStart. The next CALL was to ntdll.RtlExitUserThread, which called ntdll.RtlExitUserProcess which called ntdll.NtTerminateProcess which did a "CALL DWORD PTR FS:[0C0]" that exited the process once returned.  When linked with the MSVCRT 7.1: once main() RET's back to _mainCRTStartup, this results in a MSVCR71.exit -> MSVCR71.doexit -> KERNEL32.ExitProcess which in turn calls ntdll.RtlExitUserProcess and this picks up the same as above.

Comment: @PeterCordes: As an addendum to the comment above, I did not observe the Windows loader placing the ExitProcess' address artificially on the stack in either the pure-asm or CRT tests.  I am curious about this because its been mentioned by multiple people. If this did happen, I'm thinking it must have been an older version of Windows? Does anyone remember which?

Comment: @byteptr: It's something I've read but never tested myself, since I don't use Windows.  Linux doesn't do anything of the sort (`[rsp]` = argc on process entry), so returning from the entry point just crashes.  **I may have invented the actual "ExitProcess as return address" specific detail in my own mind** after someone commented that in Windows, returning from the entry point does call ExitProcess.  (Or maybe they just said "exit your process").  ExitProcess() apparently takes an exit-status arg, so it's unlikely.

Comment: I'm confused; does `ntdll.RtlExitUserProcess` not exit all threads of a process?  Your testing shows that returning from the entry point runs the same code as ExitProcess(), right?  But this accepted answer is saying that doing that only exits the thread that returned.

Comment: @PeterCordes: byteptr's debugging session shows that `RtlExitUserThread` is called, which is consistent with Raymond's post and my own observations.  It seems safe to assume that `RtlExitUserThread` only calls `RtlExitUserProcess` when the exiting thread is the last one in the process.  (I would have naively expected that to happen in the kernel, but now that I think about it, it has to happen in user mode in order to support DllMain.)  Time permitting, I'll double-check that myself when I get back to the office tomorrow.

Comment: @byteptr, if any version of Windows ever put ExitProcess on the stack, my guess would be 16-bit Windows.  It is unlikely to have ever been true of Windows NT.  I'm not sure about the Windows 95 line.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Ah that makes sense.  It sounds plausible that the "am I the last thread" logic is in user-space, so the `RtlExitUserProcess` call only happens in that special case.  (Very different from Linux, where `SYS_exit` and `SYS_exit_group` are separate kernel system calls.  And calling SYS_exit from the last thread destroys the process with no further user-space code running).

Comment: After my main-thread-only console sample returns, ntdll.RtlExitUserThread does the following: ntdll.NtQueryInformationThread(-2,0x0C,&stack_dword,4,0) is called
(NOTE: 0x0C is not a THREADINFOCLASS defined in the public winternl.h) which returns zero (NTSTATUS success) and a dword return of 1.  If the API returned a negative NTSTATUS or a nonzero value via the dword (which was true), ntdll.LdrShutdownThread, ntdll.TpCheckTerminateWorker and ntdll.NtTerminateThread would be called first.  That not being true in my case, these calls are skipped and we go directly to ntdll.RtlExitUserProcess.

Comment: To clarify that a little, although it looks as if ntdll.RtlExitUserProcess will be called in either case, it isn't, because the call to ntdll.NtTerminateThread never returns, i.e., the thread is terminating itself.

Comment: @byteptr - 0x0C - this is `ThreadAmILastThread` so `RtlExitUserThread` called `RtlExitUserProcess` only if "am I the last thread", otherwise LdrShutdownThread + `ZwTerminateThread(0, exitcode)`. interesting if call `ZwTerminateThread(0, exitcode)` - it terminate caller thread, but only if it not last thread in process. in another case - `STATUS_CANT_TERMINATE_SELF` we got (read it description in `ntstatus.h`. possible situation when 2 thread in process in same time called ExitThread. both got false for  `ThreadAmILastThread`, both go to `ZwTerminateThread`, but one from this 2 calls will fail.

Comment: and `RtlExitUserProcess` will be called - so that after  `ZwTerminateThread(0, exitcode)` go call to `RtlExitUserProcess(exitcode)` have more sense then first looking. if not do this - will be crash or undefined behavior - NtTerminateThread CAN return error - `Indicates that a thread attempted to terminate itself by default (called NtTerminateThread with NULL) and it was the last thread in the current process.`

Comment: *always be additional threads present* - if want be even more exactly - now loader threads design to exit after 30 seconds of idle(no tasks) - so can be and single thread in process. but anyway `ExitProcess` call is mandatory (direct or by some CRT)