# Does the Win32 entry point have to preserve any registers values (callee-saved registers)?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, nasm

I am writing a program in NASM, and I do not want to link it with the CRT, and so I will specify the entry point (which will be the Win32 entry point). This is the program source code:

```
global _myEntryPoint

section .text
_myEntryPoint:
    mov eax, 12345
```

Now this is what I know about the Win32 entry point (please correct me if I am wrong):

- The Win32 entry point does not return a value like a normal
  function does (to exit the Win32 entry point I have to call
  `ExitProcess()`).
- The Win32 entry point does not take any arguments.

Now what I don't know is the following:

- Does the Win32 entry point have to preserve any registers values (callee-saved registers)? I think the answer is *No*, since when the Win32 entry point exits, it terminates the process and not return execution to a function that expects some registers values to be preserved.

Comment: [WinMain is just the conventional name for the Win32 process entry point](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110525-00/?p=10573).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is ExitProcess necessary under Win32 when you can use a RET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904632/why-is-exitprocess-necessary-under-win32-when-you-can-use-a-ret)

Comment: That's not really a duplicate. It explains the consequences of returning from the entry point, and concludes, that there aren't any good reasons to do so. It doesn't explain, if (and which) registers to preserve, if you opt to return from the entry point. I'm not sure whether the OP really needs to know, but that's what the question is asking for.

Comment: @IInspectable, at the time I thought it might clear up some confusion - the OP states as a premise that you can't return from the entry point, but then asks whether you need to preserve registers, which doesn't really make sense.  But in retrospect I think you're right.  I'll retract the close vote.

Comment: entry point this is only function. if we direct call `ExitProcess` does not matter save we some registers or not. if we return - need save/restore register as in any usual functions - *ebx,ebp,edi,esi,esp* in x86 and *rbx,rbp,rdi,rsi,rsp,r12-r15* in amd64.

Comment: An APC starts at `LdrInitializeThunk`, which is passed a thread context to resume after initialization. The context has the executable's entry point and the initial thread parameter, a pointer to the PEB in case of the initial thread. The context resumes at `RtlUserThreadStart`, which for a Windows app calls `BaseThreadInitThunk`, which calls the designated entry point. The PEB pointer argument is typically ignored. In `RtlExitUserProcess` the loader regains control to shut down the process, and then the process gets terminated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in [my answer to the proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39904632/886887), you shouldn't return from the Win32 entry point at all, in which case there is obviously no need for you to preserve any registers.  The way your question is phrased vaguely suggests that you were worried that you night need to restore registers before calling `ExitProcess` but this is definitely not the case; calling `ExitProcess` does not cause you to return from the entry point, [it just stops running your code](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070503-00/?p=27003).  (See also [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100122-00/?p=15193/) for an update, and [this may also be of interest](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070504-00/?p=26983/).)

Should you ignore that advice and return from the entry point anyway, well, in practice the answer is the same: you don't actually need to have preserved any registers.  To the best of my knowledge this behaviour is not documented, however, so if you wanted to be cautious you might choose to strictly follow the `stdcall` convention.