# Assembly program does not exit

Tags: assembly

I am trying to create my first executable file in assembly and I have a problem that the application never exits (I must terminate it manually). 
Code:

```
[bits 32]
extern _puts

section .data

testString:
db "Test"

section .text

_WinMain@16:
push testString
call _puts
add esp,4
xor eax,eax
ret
```

I compile it using NASM 2.13.01 and ld.exe 2.28 (on Windows 10)

```
nasm -f Win32 -p first_exe.obj first_exe.asm
ld first_exe.obj -o first_exe.exe c:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
```

My friend told me it works on his computer with the same NASM version, but ld 2.24 (windows 8)

Is it problem with ld, Windows 10 or my code is just wrong? Are there any workarounds for it, except calling exit function?

Thanks for help

Comment: Related, with maybe some more details or links to 
docs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46294072/does-the-win32-entry-point-have-to-preserve-any-registers-values-callee-saved-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning from `WinMain` does not terminate your application. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx) is pretty clear that you need to do this yourself. There is another error, too: C strings must be terminated with a NUL byte, so your `testString` should be defined like this:

```
testString:
    db "Test",0
```

Comment: Yeah, i pasted it wrong, sorry.

Comment: I wrote this code with this tutorial https://youtu.be/WNfC7hpuO_U?t=11m52s Why it worked there without exit?

Comment: @BOAKGP I don't know, I don't speak Polish.

Comment: @BOAKGP: different versions of Windows might not start any extra threads, and thus exit your process when `WinMain` returns.

Comment: Ok, it's now clear. Thanks a lot